# URL Amigável não carrega conteúdo

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Bem, estou aqui com um problema na url amigável, estou a fazer as rotas através do ficheiro `.htaccess` e pegar os valor por `$_GET`.Só que quando entro na url o conteúdo não me é carregado, fica a pagina sempre a tentar carregar e nada.

Ficheiro htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^estabelecimentos\/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)\/ index.php?controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Não dá nenhum erro de PHP ou erro 500 do apache, por exemplo?

Comment: Não apresenta qualquer erro por ver o que acontece neste link http://sabeonde.pt/estabelecimentos/bares/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua página não carrega porque dá erro de javascript. Como sua URL amigável contém um "subdiretório", os caminhos relativos dos seus arquivos `.js` acabam se tornando inválidos.

Você precisa adicionar uma tag [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) na seção `head` do seu HTML.

```
<base href="http://sabeonde.pt/">
```

Essa tag vai colocar `http://sabeonde.pt/` antes de cada URL relativa na hora de carregar o conteúdo.

Comment: foi isso mesmo corrigiu, só uma pergunta e possível na url que agora esta assim http://sabeonde.pt/estabelecimentos/bares/ ficar so http://sabeonde.pt/bares/

Comment: @CésarSousa Não testei, mas acho que simplesmente removendo `estabelecimentos\` do `.htaccess` vai funcionar.

Comment: Tentei ai como você disse e nao funcionou

Comment: @CésarSousa Troque a linha do `RewriteRule` por `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [L]`

Comment: Amigo e isso mesmo valeu pela sua ajuda foi preciosa mesmo

Comment: Estou aqui com outro problema relativamente a essa linha que me deu para trocar resolveu um problema mas agora tentei criar a mesma linha mas para outro ficheiro mas cai sempre nessa regra estabelecimentos como posso resolver isso

Comment: @CésarSousa Esse já é um problema diferente. Crie outra pergunta e descreva isso lá.

Comment: Já coloquei uma pergunta nova